# WPF Popup Closing Animatiom

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 <Popup     
            AllowsTransparency="True" 
            Focusable="False"                                
            PopupAnimation="Slide"  
            Width="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=ActualWidth}"
            Height ="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=ActualHeight}"
            Name="popup" 
            Placement="Relative" 
            PlacementTarget="{Binding grid}" >                    
        </Popup>
```

This popup opens by slide animation perfectly when i set it's IsOpen Property to True. but why Popup closes immediately without any animation.
Is there a way to animate Popup closing ?

Answer (score 0):

The current WPF implementation only supports the `PopupAnimation.Fade` animation for closing the popup.

You can check this in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/Popup.cs,b7c579e907b02b59):

```
if (animation == PopupAnimation.Fade)
{
    _popupRoot.Value.SetupFadeAnimation(AnimationDelayTime, visible);
    return true;
}
else if (visible) // only translate when showing popup
{
    // translate the content
    _popupRoot.Value.SetupTranslateAnimations(animation, AnimationDelayTime, AnimateFromRight, AnimateFromBottom);
    return true;
}
```

For `PopupAnimation.Fade`, both the showing and the closing are animated. For other animation types, only the `visible` (showing) state is animated.

You cannot change this behavior. You could of course attach a custom animation to your content, but the popup will be closed immediately anyway, so you won't see it:

```
if (!animating)
    _secHelper.HideWindow();
```

If you can, use adorners instead of popups. There, you can setup your animation as you need. Alternatively, use the fade animation for popups.